# EXCEL matching elements in a discontinuous range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to be able to create a list of matching elements from two columns in different worksheets.

Let me provide a mock example:
I have two lists of elements, in this case boys names and girls names. Those will be placed in different sheets. In the figure below, for simplicity, they are placed in different columns (discontinuos range). I want the formula to generate the list in cells A3:A14 (list all elements in the discontinuous range which match containing the text "jo".

[image]

I've learned that the best way to provide such discontinuous range to a formula is by defining a named range.

So far, what I got is:

```
{IF(  
    MATCH(
        INDEX(Named_Range,
        SMALL(IF(Named_Range="*"&$A$3&"*",
                ROW(Named_Range)-ROW(INDEX(Named_Range,1,1))+1),ROW()-1)), 
        '(Names)'!C:C,
        0),
    INDEX(Named_Range,
        SMALL(IF(Named_Range="*"&$A$3&"*",
            ROW(Named_Range)-ROW(INDEX(Named_Range,1,1))+1),
        ROW()-1)),
    "")
}
```

Named_Range is declared as 
`=D9:D13,F3:F6`

The small function returns the nth element matching the criteria. It should also MATCH one of the names in (Names)!C:C. If so, I get the value of that cell. For the sake of simplicity, consider that '(Names)'!C:C contains all names, so it will always be true.

This formula worked for me using a single column as the range. However, I cannot evaluate the formula using the discontinuous range without Excel crashing, so I'm looking for a piece of advice on how to get it right.
Thanks.

Comment: lol! Formula in an image... Please add it in text too! ;)

Comment: Much harder to structure it clearly with my cell phone. Will post it in text so people can copy it.

Comment: It is very hard to understand your requirement from formula. Isn't it better put some of your data desired output, so that we can understand and make formula to solve.

Comment: Added a mock example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Perhaps the best way to deal with a discontinuous range is to make it continuous...?*

Your problem can be simplified a lot with a small VBA function. This function takes a discontinuous named range and returns a single continuous column containing all the same values. That way you can use your `INDEX/MATCH/SMALL` etc formulas in the normal way

```
Function Arrange(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim temp As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim r As Range

    ReDim temp(1 To rng.Cells.Count)
    i = 1

    For Each r In rng
        temp(i) = r.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next r

    Arrange = Application.Transpose(temp)
End Function
```

After you have added this code to a new module in your VBA editor you will be able to use it like this on the worksheet:

```
=INDEX(ARRANGE(Named_Range),1)
```

To get the first element, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @CallumDA. One question, though: is there a way of getting the actual row number of the current element in the array? I have to get other elements in the same sheet and row than the matching element.

Comment: You could have another function, say `ArrangeRow` which does all the same things but rather than `temp(i) = r.Value` use `temp(i)=r.Row`

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly what needed (as example is simplified), but gave me a very good pointer.